# Returning Dict from SQlite3 Database query return sqlite3.Row error

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am running a function which is currently printing a list of Dictionaries by extracting data from a SQLite database. However, when using return instead of print, I get an error as **sqlite3.Row object at 0x04AD4980** and no data is displayed (in debug mode).

From what I read, in order to return *dict* data format from a *Sql query*, I should use *row_factory* which I did and worked fine when printing only.

Any idea please?

**Database Details:**
**Database Name:** 'testDB'

**Test_Table**: Name,Age,Dob

```
import sqlite3

    def queryData () :

        conn = sqlite3.connect ( 'TestDB.db' )
        # row_factory to create dictionary cursor
        conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
        cursor = conn.cursor ( )
    
        cursor.execute ( "select * from test_table" )
        rows = cursor.fetchall ( )
    
        for row in rows :
            
            return ({ row [ 'name' ] } , { row [ 'age' ] } , { row [ 'dob' ] })
            ## with print, it works
            ## print ({ row [ 'name' ] } , { row [ 'age' ] } , { row [ 'dob' ] })
    
    
    def main () :
        queryData ( )
```

Comment: which line gives exactly what error? The posted code does not produce an error (when `main` is executed and at least one row is selected).

Comment: the return line give the error in debug mode. If executed without debug mode, you won't see any error

Answer (score 0):

That is not an error. It is telling you that `row` is a [sqlite3.Row object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Row) that lives *at* that memory location. This snippet doesn't "do" anything with `row` unless it is `print`ed. As written, it is working properly.

Using a row factory doesn't return a dict object. It returns a sqlite3.Row object which "*supports mapping access by column name*" much like a dictionary. Perhaps study the example [in the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Row) more carefully to see how row factory can be used to build the program you want.